# Hypergeometric Distribution - Probability of Teams Ending in Same Group - Need help with part b)

Tags: probability, statistics

No answers to refer to. I would be really greatful if someone could take a look if my procedure looks fine to solve this problem. Also, for part b) I got a bit confused in regards to how to proceed so any tips would be amazing! Thanks in advance for your time!

18 teams, 5 of which are professional, take part in a football tournament. At the beginning of the tournament the 18 teams are randomly divided into two groups (A and B) of 9 teams each. Determine the probabilities of the following events:

a) all professional teams end up in one group

It looks to me that this is a Hypergeometric Distribution as we have no replications and order doesn't matter. From here it follows that:

$N=18 $
$K=5$ $n=9$ $k=5$

By using: $P(k)=[\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}]:\binom{N}{n}$ and plug in the above values we get:

$P(5)=[\binom{5}{5}\binom{18-5}{9-5}]:\binom{18}{9}=0.01470$

b) two of the professional teams are in one group, and the other tree professional teams are in the other group.

So basically, we use the formula from above, just with different values.
This time we have: $N=18 $
$K=5$ $n=9$ $k=2$

$P(2)=[\binom{5}{2}\binom{18-5}{9-2}]:\binom{18}{9}=0.03529$

However, I'm a bit confused now: do I just do the same for the other condition (that 3 teams are in the other group)? Or perhaps just 1 - P(2)? Or is it something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are **almost** okay.

Concerning a)

Your answer is actually the probability that all professional teams end up in team $A$ and also equals the probability that all professional teams end up in team $B$.

But needed is the probability that all professional teams end up in team $A$ or end up in team $B$.

These events are mutually exclusive and equiprobable so your answer will be okay if it is multiplied by $2$.

In your interpretation $9$ teams are selected out of $18$ and the selected teams (among which $5$ are professional and $13$ are not) will receive label $A$ (or - if you like that better - label $B$).

b) similarly the answer is here: $$\frac{\binom52\binom{13}3+\binom53\binom{13}2}{\binom{18}5}$$i.e. the probability that $2$ professional teams receive label $A$ plus the probability that $3$ professional teams receive label $A$.

In both cases $2$ of the professional teams are in one group and the other $3$ are in the other group.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaning! Makes sense now :)

Comment: You are very welcome.